# Problemas al hacer select box dependientes

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Buenas, tengo problemas al hacer select dependiente de otro. He probado con:

http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-selects-dependientes-mediante-eventos/

Pero no he logrado hacer que funcione, el problema es que relacionan con varias entidades pero lo que yo quiero es relacionar con una sola entidad.

Estas dos variables necesito crear un formulario donde sean select. Ambas tendrán información de dos variables de una entidad. Pero una depende de otra (version depende de año), donde existirán varias versiones pero cada una esta con un año. Al seleccionar un año se despliegan las versiones relacionadas al año.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="año", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $anio;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $version;
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza este Bundle funciona con `Symfony 3.x` y también hay soporte para `Symfony 2.x` con este [Bundle](https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle)
Primero debes instalar algunas dependencias como [BraincraftedBootstrapBundle](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/) 
El detalle de la instalación [aqui](https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle#installation)

Un ejemplo del uso, esto va dentro del Form y depende las entidades que estes utilizando:

```
$builder
   ->add('country', Select2EntityType::class, [
            'multiple' => true,
            'remote_route' => 'tetranz_test_default_countryquery',
            'class' => '\Tetranz\TestBundle\Entity\Country',
            'primary_key' => 'id',
            'text_property' => 'name',
            'minimum_input_length' => 2,
            'page_limit' => 10,
            'allow_clear' => true,
            'delay' => 250,
            'cache' => true,
            'cache_timeout' => 60000, // if 'cache' is true
            'language' => 'en',
            'placeholder' => 'Select a country',
            // 'object_manager' => $objectManager, // inject a custom object / entity manager 
        ])
```

Antes debes colocar el `use` al Bundle:

```
use Tetranz\Select2EntityBundle\Form\Type\Select2EntityType;
```

Para mas detalle de todo lo que puedes hacer [aquí](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)